# Inconsistent ability to resolve DNS on Ubuntu 12.10 fresh install

Tags: 12.10, dns, dd-wrt

For machines on my local network I use my router (running DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) std-nokaid-small) to DHCP IP addresses and to resolve names.  I now frequently notice that my web browsers can't resolve these names until after I open a terminal window and `dig mycomputer.mylan@192.168.1.100` (the router) or sometimes try some other networking commands.  This happens on both wired and wifi devices on the local network.

Here is an example:

```
jelevin@mycomputer:~$ ping mycomputer.lan
ping: unknown host mycomputer.lan
jelevin@mycomputer:~$ host mycomputer.lan
mycomputer.lan has address 192.168.1.236
jelevin@guava:~$ ping mycomputer.lan
PING guava.family (192.168.1.236) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from guava.family (192.168.1.236): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
...
```

I have reinstalled and dpkg-reconfigered resolvconf.  Here is the contents of /etc/resolv.conf

```
jelevin@mycomputer:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search lan
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the known bug #1003842 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1003842).

To work around this bug, edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`, then `restart network-manager`.